# activex z-index

Tags: activex

I am displaying 2 activex on a webpage. The one show streaming from a camera, the other showing a .avi file.

I want to display the one over the other.
But no success. The one that show .avi always above the one shows streaming from camera.

I use an iframe for each activex.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just resize the one you want to not display to 1px by 1px to "hide" it and it should be fine.